# Anyone have syntax for removing all components at once from COM+ Application using Powershell

Tags: powershell, com+

I am having problems trying to loop through and remove 91 components from my COM+ Application

This is my Powershell code:

```
$app = $apps | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'pkgAdap2'}
$compColl = $apps.GetCollection("Components", $app.Key)
$compColl.Populate()

$index = 0
foreach($component in $compColl) {

    $compColl.Remove($index)
    $compColl.SaveChanges()

    $index++
}
```

The code appears to work but it only removes HALF of the components and for the rest of the `$index` the loop returns this error:

```
Value does not fall within the expected range.
At line:4 char:5
+     $compColl.Remove($index)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException
```

So I keep running it and the number of components left keeps getting reduced by half.

I think the reason is that the array/collection I am "removing" from re-sorts the remaining indexes, moving them over every time. So I only get through half before `$index` is out of range. It is the only thing I can figure is doing this. Thus I also tried another approach:

```
while($compColl.Count > 0) {
    $compColl.Remove($compColl.Count)
}
```

But it doesn't work either.

Does anyone know how to delete all components at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the indices of your collection are `0`-based, so the following should work:

```
while($compColl.Count -gt 0) {    
  $compColl.Remove($compColl.Count - 1) # remove last element, which updates .Count. Using 0 to remove the first one is a good option to.
}
$compColl.SaveChanges()
```

If you're sure that the collection won't change while you're enumerating it, this variant is probably slightly more efficient:

```
for ($i = $compColl.Count - 1; $i -ge 0; --$i) {
  $compColl.Remove($i)
}
$compColl.SaveChanges()
```

---

The problem with your original approach was that every `$compColl.Remove($index)` call implicitly decremented the indices of the remaining items, so that `$index++` ended up *skipping* items until it reached a value beyond the remaining highest index and failed.

Generally, it's problematic to loop over a collection item by item while modifying that collection in the loop body.

Comment: The second one worked like a charm. First one probably works too, but decided to go with your advice. And yes, I agree with why my version wasn't working because the indices were being decremented.